# Properties of Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Prove that there is no continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for $c \in \mathbb{R}$ the equation $f(x)=c$ has exactly two solutions.
This is what I have so far.

Proof by contradiction, suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and the equation $f(x)=c$ has exactly two solutions, $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$.  On the interval $[a,b], f(t)\leq c$ for all $t$, or $f(t) \geq c$ for all $t$.  Assume the latter.  Then $f(t)<c$ for $t<a$ and $f(t)<c$ for $t>b$.  $f$ has a maximum value on $[a,b]$ at exactly two points, $d$ and $g$, assume $d<g$.  Now choose any $t$ such that $d<t<g$.  Then $f(a)=c<f(t)<f(d)$ and $f(b)=c<f(t)<f(g)$.  So the equation $f(x)=f(t)$ has three solutions, $t, c_{1}, c_{2}$ where $a<c_{1}<d$ and $g<c_{2}<b$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Some more effort in posing a question would be nice

Comment: What about $f(x) = x^2$, with $c=1$?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "has exactly two solutions *for any $c$*"

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean, as Alex Becker suggested in the comments, that *for any* $c$ the equation $f(x)=c$ has exactly two solutions, then your proof is complete as you found three distinct solutions to one of those equations.

Moreover, you could also significantly shorten your proof by noting that $f$ is unbounded both from above and from below. After showing $f(t)<c$ whenever $t<a$ or $t>b$, we see that $f$ is unbounded in the closed interval $[a,b]$, which is a contradiction to the continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1(c), x_2(c)$ be two distinct solutions of $f(x) = c$ chosen so that both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are continuous functions. $x_1(c) \neq x_2(c)$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, assume w.l.o.g. that $x_1(c) < x_2(c)$. Thus, the image of the function $x \mapsto (x, f(x))$ is not connected. But $\mathbb{R}$ is connected and $f$ is continuous - contradiction.